# Can I get 4k60 using a DP1.4-to-HDMI21 cable?

Tags: intel-graphics, 4k-resolution

I'll be connecting my PC running i5-8500T to a 4k60 TV.

This is the video specs from the Intel Ark site.

> [image]

Comment: The maximum refresh over HDMI will be 24Hz. If you want 60 Hz use DisplayPort

Comment: @Ramhound That is what they are asking. If they use an adaptor from Displayport to HDMI can they get 4K@60

Comment: @Mokubai - The first sentence covered their question. The maximum refresh rate will be 24Hz due to the HDMI connection being used at the iGPU. HDMI to DisplayPort is one way. The way I read those specifications is that an HDMI source will be limited to 24Hz.

Comment: Just a comment regarding the conventions of this site: Do not put the question in the title. The title is to get people's attention, it is not the place to put the question.

Comment: @mrjayviper, you have accepted the answer. Does it mean that it worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a passive adaptor, *maybe*, but probably not. It depends on how the output is wired at the graphics card but the transceivers on the DisplayPort output may only work properly for a true DisplayPort output.

If you get an active adaptor that fully supports DisplayPort input and 4K60 HDMI output then it *should* work. The key thing is to be certain you are getting an adaptor with active electronics capable of converting DP to HDMI. [This one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/DisplayPort-Adapter-Compatible-ThinkPad-Desktop/dp/B07ZNNRYFL) claims to be such an adaptor, and the reviews seem to back it up.